# Populating Field from Multiple Input Fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to populate a field with Street Address, City, State, and Zip but right now when I enter data into each field it replaces the last one.

```
$("#trainer_address").keyup( function () {
        $('#location').val($(this).val());
    });

    $("#trainer_city").keyup( function () {
        $('#location').val($(this).val());
    });

    $("#trainer_state").keyup( function () {
        $('#location').val($(this).val());
    });

    $("#trainer_zip").keyup( function () {
        $('#location').val($(this).val());
    });
```

How do I get it to keep the previous value, and then add the next so I can end up with something like `402 StreetAddress City State, 12345`?

Comment: It's interesting. What happens if you then return back to the first field? Should it append one more time?

Comment: You want location to be address + city + state + zip?

Answer (score 1):

This script will do it:

```
var $loc = $('#location'),
    address = [],

getAddress = function() {
    var str = address.slice(0, 3).join(' ') + ', ' + (address[3] || '');
    return str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').replace(/,\s$/, '');
}

$("#trainer_address, #trainer_city, #trainer_state, #trainer_zip").on({
    focus: function() {
        $loc.val(getAddress());
    },
    keyup: function() {
        address[$(this).index()] = $(this).val();
        $(this).trigger('focus');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J6G9f/1/

Script also correctly handles removing parts of the address and it automatically updates the result.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're overwriting it. Try concatenating:

```
$('#location').val($('#location').val() + $(this).val());
```

For example, change this:

```
$("#trainer_zip").keyup( function () {
    $('#location').val($(this).val());
});
```

to this:

```
$("#trainer_zip").keyup( function () {
    $('#location').val($('#location').val() + $(this).val());
});
```

Do that for each `keyup()` event function

Comment: confused on how to implement this solution

Answer (score 0):

concatenate the old val with new val using `+` operator...and you can avoid multiple keyup function using multiple selector....

try this

```
$("#trainer_address,#trainer_city,#trainer_state,#trainer_zip").keyup( function () {
  var location=$('#location').val();
  $('#location').val(location + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: for some reason, typing in `street` i end up with `streetstreetstreet`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native `value` like this:

```
$('#location')[0].value += this.value;
```

Comment: how do I add this solution?

Comment: You just have to replace the line where you set the value.